# Tweet programatically c#/vb windows/console application

Tags: .net, twitter, twitter-oauth

I want to post a tweet to my twitter account programatically. Its a windows application. Have created application and having key, secret, token, token secret. Have tried with TweetSharp, it didn't throw any error and no tweet too.

Tried with TweetInvi, it throws "unhandled exception in initialize"

My target framework is .net 3.0

Have anyone come across these errors or know any other alternative solution? I dn't mind which 3rd party tool to use. Just want to make a tweet programatically . Any help would be appreciated . Thanks in advance

Comment: Post code, get help.  No code, bugs remain.

Answer (score 0):

Tweetinvi minimal .NET Framework support is 4.0.
You will no be able to use Tweetinvi for .NET 3.0.